# Vector function derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

If a function $f(t,x)$ has $x \in  \mathbb{R}^{2}$, what is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$?
Thank you greatly.

Comment: There is more than one form of derivative for functions of several variables. Look up divergence, gradient and curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such context, $\partial f/\partial x$ can simply denote $(\partial f/\partial x_1, \partial f/\partial x_2)$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Probably this is the most common meaning of it.

Comment: I thought it could  be a Jacobian, since the question is if $f \in C^{1}$.

Comment: The notation $(\partial f/\partial x_1,\partial f/\partial x_2)$ is used for Jacobian as well, since it equals $\begin{pmatrix} \partial f_1/\partial x_1 & \partial f_1/\partial x_2 \\ \partial f_2/\partial x_1 & \partial f_2/\partial x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ for $f=(f_1,f_2)$.